# Automatically updating dependencies in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one question I think is pretty simple. Could you explain me why sometimes package.json is automatically updates and sometimes don't. e.g. if I installed `express` or `gulp` these plugins were added to dependencies automatically. But if I installed `express-jwt` or `mongodb` these plugins were not added

Comment: You may have been copying documentation for installing from project pages, some which had `--save` and some which didn't. Only the `--save` ones are added to `package.json`.

Answer (score 3):

They are added to `package.json` when you append one of the following flags:

`-S|--save|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional`

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install for full documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a package with the **`--save`** or **`--save-dev`** flag, these are persisted to the **dependencies** or **devDependencies** arrays respectively.

If no flag is added, the package is downloaded but not persisted to **package.json**

*Edit: There's is also the more obscure --save-optional flag, but it'd say it's mostly out of scope for this particular case.*

Answer (score 1):

If we use the following command to install npm dependencies-

npm install express-jwt --save
or 
npm install mongodb --save

these installed dependencies will also be added to package.json file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I installed express-jwt using npm install express and now I have to uninstall express-jwt and install again using --save?

Comment: If they are not there in package.json right now, go ahead and give these commands a try. They should add these to the file.